# Calling functions in a Lua table from C++

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I have for example, a [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) table/object:

```
bannana
```

And this Lua table has a function inside it called `chew`, that takes a parameter

```
bannana.chew(5)
```

I have also used [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG), and have for example a class `CPerson`:

```
class CPerson {
    public:
        // ....
        void Eat();
        // ....
};
```

I can obtain an instance of this object from Lua:

```
person = engine:getPerson()
```

What I need to be able to do is the following Lua code:

```
person = engine:getPerson()
person:Eat(bannana)
```

Where `person:eat` would call the `chew` function in the `bannana` table, passing a parameter.

Since `CPerson` is implemented in C++, what changes are needed to implement `Eat()` assuming the `CPerson` class already has a Lua state pointer?

**Edit1:** I do not want to know how to bind C++ classes to Lua, I already have SWIG to do this for me, I want to know how to call Lua functions inside Lua tables, from C++.

**Edit2:** The `CPerson` class and `bannana` table, are both general examples, it can be assumed that the `CPerson` class already has a LuaState pointer/reference, and that the function signature of the `Eat` method can be changed by the person answering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ignoring any error checking ...

```
lua_getglobal(L, "banana"); // or get 'banana' from person:Eat()
lua_getfield(L, -1, "chew");
lua_pushinteger(L, 5);
lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe "[Simpler Cpp Binding](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimplerCppBinding)" will be helpful.

Comment: this doesnt help me, all this tells me is how to pass literals, how to bind C++ to lua with luna, and how to pass C++ objects around with lua.

Comment: What I asked for, is how to call a method on a lua table from C++, I already have SWIG to bind C++ to lua for me

Comment: what is the exact signature of the CPerson's Eat method (generated by SWIG, I suppose ?) From what I undersand, what you want is the CPerson class to get the 'bannana' lua table, right ? I think for that you need to get a handler on the corresponding luaState ...

Comment: its an example, the person who answers the question is free to meddle with the definition of CPerson::Eat as is necessary, it is safe to assume the LuaState has already been passed to the CPerson object beforehand, and that only one such LuaState is present.