# Tracking Lua tables in C

Tags: c++, c, lua, swig

I have C++ objects and I have [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) objects/tables. (Also have [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) C++ bindings.)

What I need to be able to do is associate the two objects so that if I do say

```
CObject* o1 = getObject();
o1->Update();
```

it will do the equivalent Lua:

```
myluatable1.Update();
```

So far I can imagine that CObject::Update would have the following code:

```
void CObject::Update(){
    // Acquire table.

    // ???

    // Do the following operations on the table.
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "Update");
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

How would I store/set the Lua table to be used, and what would go in the  `// ???` above to make the Update call work?

Comment: Could one assign the c++ object an integer id, and store the associated table in a global lau table aka globaltable[tableID] = associatedTable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I cant believe nobody noticed this!

http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.2.html

A section of the Lua API for storing references to lua objects and tables and returning references for the purposes of being stored in C structures!!

Comment: Could you please expand on using this section. I'm trying to do exactly this, but struggling a little bit with implementation. Do you have a brief example you could show? I'd be grateful! Thanks.

Comment: That line of code is essentially calling the lua: ai:Init() from a c++ context

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for an example of storing a reference id to a lua table, and then pushing it back to the stack. I figured out how to do it though. Thanks for following up!

Comment: +1 This helped lead me in the right direction along with the previous section of the doc at: http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.1.html which talks about the registry. Note that the linked sample in the comment however now points to a blank line.

Answer (score 2):

I am curious for the reasons of this "reverse SWIG"...

The objects in Lua live within the Lua contexts, so at a minimum you would need to store "L" inside your object.

The issue of passing the "table pointer" is a bit more delicate - even though Lua allows to retrieve the pointer off the Lua stack (using lua_topointer()), there is no way of putting that back. Understandingly - because otherwise one would also need to check that the pointer does point to a valid object, etc, etc.

What you might do however, is to store the references to the tables in the global table, the index being the lightuserdata being the pointer to your object. Then by having the Lua state, and the name of the global array, you can retrieve the reference to the table and push it onto the Lua stack for that context.

This is sketchy, and I haven't even touched the question of garbage-collecting with this construct.

But in any case this is not going to be the speed racer performance-wise, and looks like a lot of boilerplate C++ code to me. I'd try to reconsider the approach and push some of what you want to do into the Lua domain.

p.s. looks like it is the third question which seems almost a dupe of the previous two ones, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792678/wrapping-a-lua-object-for-use-in-c-with-swig) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888672/calling-functions-in-a-lua-table-from-c) are the previous ones. If those were not answered fully, would have been better to edit them/add the bounty to accumulate the answers.

Comment: the 3 questions have their differences although they have the same eventual goal, I can move all this into pure lua in one project solving the problem, but this for another project it would require me to rewrite large swathes of the project.